# Eliminar etiqueta [vistas], pues es ambigua

Tags: discusión, solicitud-de-quemado

¿Describe [vistas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas) el contenido de las preguntas en donde es aplicada la etiqueta? ¿Es clara?

- Sí, pero no es claro su uso, es confuso

¿Se encuentra el concepto en conformidad con el tema de la comunidad?

- Sí, pero es ambigua.

¿Añade la etiqueta algún contenido valioso a la aportación?

- No, porque es ambigua por tanto presta a confusión.

¿Significa lo mismo en todos los contextos comunes?

- No, porque en cada sistema referencia a una cosa: una vista puede una interfaz de usuario como también una vista de base de datos.

Actualmente tiene [36 preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas) en contextos distintos, y su definición es todo lo que puede ser. La coloco a continuación:

> Esta etiqueta es referente a para preguntas sobre vistas de base de
>   datos o vistas de interfaz de usuario (UI). Ver también las siguientes
>   etiquetas: vistas, vista-sql, vista-android, vistaUI.

Answer (score -1):

Personalmente considero que la etiqueta no es ambigua diría que es de uso general, pero no es confusa:

- que la Etiqueta sean de uso general y este de uso en varios y distintos lenguajes de programación no la hace ambigua.
- decir que una etiqueta es confusa y ambigua requiere sustentación basada en que bases lo determinaste, no solo decir es ambigua y confusa.
- el contexto del uso de la etiqueta esta claro en sus descripción. solo se presta para confusiones para aquellas personas que la usen o la lean sin conocer el contexto .

en resumidas solo se presta para confusiones a las personas que no están relacionadas a la terminología:

Por ejemplo si yo veo un post que mescla las etiquetas [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) o [sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) o [base-de-dato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-dato) y al lado le coloca [vistas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas) claramente puedo identificar que se trata de una vista de base de datos, o si el contenido esta relacionado a un código de uno de estas estructuras, tambien tengo claro que se esta hablando sobre una vista de base de datos.

Por Ejemplo si yo veo un post que mescla las etiquetas [symfony](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) o [laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) o [blade](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blade) y al lado le coloca [vistas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas) claramente puedo identificar que se trata de una vista de la Interface de Usuario, o si el contenido esta relacionado a un código de uno de estas estructuras, tambien tengo claro que se esta hablando sobre una vista de Interface de Usuario.

Según la ayuda, es de suma importancia colocar las etiquetas relevante a el contenido del POST he utilizar la etiqueta [vistas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas) por si sola aportara poco como dices pero ayuda a ubicarte si de tu interés.

Aun así considerando tu opinión como valida, lo pertinente seria des-ambiguar la etiqueta creando mas etiqueta como [vistas-base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas-base-de-datos) y [vistas-interface-de-usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vistas-interface-de-usuario)